# MAF (System.Addin) property of serializable type in contract?

Tags: c#, .net, maf, system.addin

We are testing the MAF addin to use as our addin framework. But we get stuck at a basic issue. Can we use serializable types as IContract parameters?

Both the contract and the parameter type is defined in the same assembly:

```cs
    public interface IHostContract : IContract
    {
        void SetCurrent(TheValue tagValue);   // does not work
        void SetCurrentSimple(double value);  // works fine
    }

    [Serializable]
    public sealed class TheValue
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public double Value { get; set; }
    }
```

We are able to get everything up and running. Calling the SetCurrent results in an exception:
    AppDomainUnloadedException :

```
The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback(Context ctx, IntPtr ctxID, Int32 appDomainID, InternalCrossContextDelegate ftnToCall, Object[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
```

Loading and running of plugins:

```cs
public void Run(string PluginFolder)
{
    AddInStore.Rebuild(PluginFolder);
    Collection<AddInToken> tokens = AddInStore.FindAddIns(typeof(Plugins.IPlugin), PluginFolder);

    foreach (var token in tokens)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found addin: " + token.Name + " v" + token.Version);
        try
        {
            var plugin = token.Activate<Plugins.IPlugin>(AddInSecurityLevel.FullTrust);
            plugin.PluginHost = this;
            plugin.Start();
            plugin.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error starting plugin: " + exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Plugin:

```
[System.AddIn.AddIn("Plugin1", Version = "1.0.0")]
public class Plugin1 : IPlugin
{
    private int started;

    public Plugin1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plugin 1 created");
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plugin 1 started: {0}", started);
        started++;

        var tagValue = new TheValue { Id = 1, Value = 4.32 };
        PluginHost.SetCurrent(tagValue);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plugin 1 stopped");
    }

    public IPluginHost PluginHost { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should read carefully the following blog entry by a member of the team responsible for System.AddIn http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clraddins/archive/2007/02/27/restrictions-on-contracts.aspx TheValue should be a struct in the contracts assembly. By the way I have used System.AddIn extensively for a couple of years and I wouldn't recommend it except for exposing the host to the add-ins (like Visual Studio, MS Office etc.). If you want to create a more complex design, with add-ins that cooperate or lego designs then MEF or Mono.AddIns are better choices.

Comment: Could you update your question by adding the code that loads, and initializes the add-in?

Comment: The reason for using MAF is because we think we will need the isolation of appdomains. We must support running of old and new versions of the same plugin at the same time. We will take a look at Mono Addins as well. Updated the code in the question to include loading.

Comment: We get the same result if we use struct.

Comment: And you use IHostContract.SetCurrent in the Start method of the plugin? Is the work in Start synchronous? By the way note that this is not safe if nore that one add-ins are loaded.

Comment: That is right, we call SetCurrent. I've added the code. Not safe? Only one plugin calls this method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19768/discussion-between-julius-and-panos-rontogiannis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the guidelines for [lifetime management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384186.aspx). In each contract-to-view adapter you need to store a [ContractHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.pipeline.contracthandle.aspx). This is necessary for the lifetime management of the proxies that `System.AddIn` implicitly creates (remember that `System.AddIn` is based on .NET Remoting).

Taken from MSDN:

> The ContractHandle is critical to lifetime management. If you fail to
>   keep a reference to the ContractHandle object, garbage collection will
>   reclaim it, and the pipeline will shut down when your program does not
>   expect it. This can lead to errors that are difficult to diagnose,
>   such as AppDomainUnloadedException. Shutdown is a normal stage in the
>   life of a pipeline, so there is no way for the lifetime management
>   code to detect that this condition is an error.

If you decide to use `System.AddIn` in your application then you need the [PipelineBuilder](http://pipelinebuilder.codeplex.com/). In the discussion board you will find help on how to make it work with VS2010 (it is quite simple). I guess it will not be hard to make it work with VS2012 as well. This tool will take care all the System.AddIn intricacies for you. All you will need to do is create the contracts and `PipelineBuilder` will create the rest of the pipeline for you. It will also make sure that you follow the guidelines on how to build your contracts which is the most important thing with System.AddIn.

Before you decide on an add-in framework, don't forget to check out [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/). `MEF` can be used with [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) and provide versioning through adapters. IMHO, the only reason that anyone should choose System.AddIn is for the isolation feature. But note that 100% [isolation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clraddins/archive/2007/05/01/using-appdomain-isolation-to-detect-add-in-failures-jesse-kaplan.aspx) is only when the add-ins are loaded in a different process from the host.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I do not think we can avoid the isolation of appdomains. We will have a windows, service which needs to run continuously, loading and unloading addins.